# How to cite OER textbooks which have had the title and authors removed?

Tags: citation-style, open-access

I would like to cite an OER (Open Educational Resources) book in a concise way.  The book is available [here](https://2012books.lardbucket.org/pdfs/business-and-the-legal-environment.pdf).  The online pdf of the book says

> Normally, the author and publisher would be credited here. However, the publisher has asked for the customary
>   Creative Commons attribution to the original publisher, authors, title, and book URI to be removed. Additionally,
>   per the publisher's request, their name has been removed in some passages.

I do have the names of the authors, from the "About the Authors" page, but I don't know the original order they were listed in.  I wanted to do something like *first-author et al.* Is it fair to select the first one listed in the "About the Authors" page for that purpose?

Comment: This is interesting: https://2012books.lardbucket.org/attribution.html

Comment: Apparently, this is the "actual book": https://catalog.flatworldknowledge.com/catalog/editions/mayerleb_2-essentials-legal-environment-of-business-2-0

Comment: Unlike the owners of the lardbucket website, you are under no obligation (legal or ethical) to obscure the provenance of the books. But why "et al." when you can list all names?

Comment: @darijgrinberg - Laziness.  I want to cite two such books frequently in some homework exercises.